# How to include a js file kept in static folder in thymeleaf html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using **Spring Tool Suite** to build spring boot application and using **thymeleaf** as template engine.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
src/main/resources/static  
src/main/resources/templates
```

The HTML file is kept in `src/main/resources/templates`
and the javacript file is kept in `src/main/resources/static`

To include the javascript file in my html I have added the below line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{../static/js/policyCreations.js}"></script>
```

but I am getting bellow error in chrome console:

> GET http://localhost:8082/static/js/policyCreations.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

can anyone help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 5):

According to the official doc:

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:
>
> - /META-INF/resources/
> - /resources/
> - /static/
> - /public/

So all the files located  in the static folder can be referenced directly without specifying the static folder name.

Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/policyCreations.js}"></script>
```

Comment: please write some explanation along with the code. code only answers are generally discouraged in SO --Review